# Snippet auto-indent doesn't understand standard array formats

Tags: feature-request, bug, stack-snippets

Put the following into the JavaScript part of a snippet

```
var names = [
  "bill",
  "janet",
  "timothy,
];
```

Below that press enter. The cursor will be indented two spaces but it shouldn't be.

Similarly if you manually add something like

```
var names = [
  "bill",
  "janet",
  "timothy,
];

names.forEach(function(name) {
  console.log(name);
});
```

And then select all and press <kbd>shift-tab</kbd> it will format incorrectly as

```
var names = [
  "bill",
  "janet",
  "timothy,
];

  names.forEach(function(name) {
  console.log(name);
  });
```

Could this be fixed? It can be fairly frustrating to have to keep fighting the snippet editor